# Xaml Control Not Working After WIX Install

Tags: c#, xaml, wix, awesomium, pdfviewer

I have two controls in my `XAML` app. One is `Awesomium` and the other is the PDF Viewer `AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF` When I run the app locally from Visual Studio, when `Awesomium` encounters a pdf link it reroutes the request to the pdf viewer and everything is honky dory.

The problem is that once I try to create the standalone product via the WIX installer deal, the rerouted request seems to be handled by my locally installed Acrobat Reader instead of the  `AxAcroPDFLib` one (the PDF viewer runs outside of my XAML app.)

I thought it might have something to do with the two dlls (`Interop.AcroPDFLib.dll` and `AxInterop.AcroPDFLib.dll`)  for the reader not being registered so I used `heat.exe` to create the appropriate dll registrations, but that didn't change anything at all (no error thrown durring installation and  the PDF viewer still ran outside my app.) I even tried using the "forbidden" `SelfRegCost = "1"` on the two files and that failed to install, saying that it could not register the DLL. At this point I am a bit lost as to what I should do. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

**Update:** I tried publishing the app using VS, skipping all of the WIX stuff and the app works as intended. I am now certain that it has something to do with my WIX xml...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the problem was that I was not copying all of the necessary files to make it work...I think I went excessive on a few of these, but here is the file list that I needed to have for it to finally work (I stopped trying to register any of the DLLs using heat or otherwise):

```
AcroPDF.dll
avcodec-53.dll
avformat-53.dll
avutil-51.dll
Awesomium.Core.dll
Awesomium.Core.xml
Awesomium.dll
Awesomium.Windows.Controls.dll
Awesomium.Windows.Controls.xml
Awesomium.Windows.Forms.dll
Awesomium.Windows.Forms.xml
awesomium_process
AxInterop.AcroPDFLib.dll
MyApp.exe
MyApp.exe.config
MyApp.exe.manifest
icudt.dll
Interop.AcroPDFLib.dll
libEGL.dll
libEGLv2.dll
xinput9_1_0.dll
```

I also had `en-US.dll` in a separate `locales` folder